# How to play Mortal Kombat Arcade Kollection in offline 2-player versus mode without Xbox 360 controller under Win XP?

Tags: mortal-kombat-arcade-kollection

I have Mortal Kombat Arcade Kollection on Steam and had some problems playing it with a non-Xbox 360 USB controller - basically the Y-axis (vertical) is inverted and certain buttons are not recognized properly in the menu. Controller options in pause menu suggest compatibility only with Xbox 360 controller.

Is it possible to play 2-player versus mode on one computer using keyboard & non-Xbox 360 USB controller?

Comment: Have you tried using the Xbox360 controller emulator [x360ce](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/)? Could help with some incompatibilities.

Comment: Nice finding, will definitely try it out!

Comment: Used this program before I bought a Xbox360 controller for PC. Once set-up, it works like a charm. Some games can be a bit tricky, but there's usual help around the web.